# Where I should add cql_filter param in WMTS layers by OpenLayers v6?

Tags: openlayers, wmts

I am going to use cql_filter in wmts layers,this is my code, I read OpenLayers v6 Document , but I couldn't find params, I googled but I could'nt find any soltion, about cql_filter in WMTS Layers, If I want use WMS Layers I should insert "cql_filter" in ol.source in params option, but WMTS layer has not params, Hence, Where I should insert "cql_filter" If I use params in my code I add params like this

```
  params: {'LAYERS': `${geoServerWs}:${layers_}`,'CQL_FILTER':"objectid=16"},
```

to my code but it didn't show feature based on cql_filter

```
    var wmtsLayers=[
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          title:`${layers_}`,
          opacity: 1,
          source: new ol.source.WMTS({
            //attributions: '...',
            url: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?`,
            layer: `${geoServerWs}:${layers_}`,
  params: {'LAYERS': `${geoServerWs}:${layers_}`,'CQL_FILTER':"objectid=16"},
            matrixSet: 'EPSG:900913',
            format: 'image/png',
            serverType:'geoserver',
            tileLoadFunction:function(tile, src) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                xhr.open('GET', src);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(`${geoUserName}` + ':' + `${geoPass}`));
             xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
                    tile.getImage().onload = function() {
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
                        
        };
        tile.getImage().src = objectURL;
      };
      xhr.send();
    },
           projection: projection,
            tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
              origin:ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
              resolutions: resolutions,
              matrixIds: matrixIds,
              extent: ol.proj.transformExtent([44.03, 23.34, 63.34 ,39.78], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:900913')
              
            }),
           
    
          })
        })
      ];
```

Comment: where is the code that adds the cql filter?

Comment: And what is the error? Please edit the question and add error info.

Comment: I did mention in my question when I add params I can't see map

Comment: WMTS doesn't have a `params` option.  There are individual options for `layer`, `matrixSet`, `style`, `format` and `style`.
Additional parameters should be specified in the `dimensions` option (and can be updated using `updateDimensions()`)

Comment: I add cql_filter in dimensions option, but I didn't get any result, I think cql_filter is availabe for WMS layers only not WMTS layers

Comment: WMTS is designed to serve pre-rendered tiles. Some servers do support more dynamic rendering as vendor option but that does not belong to WMTS standard because on-demand rendering makes server side caching ineffective. In your case, a new cache would be needed for each objectid.

Comment: Geoserver is happy to handle filters in KVP WMTS requests